# How to grep only specified folder names

Tags: bash, grep, directory, ls

I have structure like this

```
201
202
203
204
205
206
2011-08-04_03-01-15
2011-08-05_03-01-15
2011-08-08_03-01-15
2011-08-09_03-00-02
2011-08-10_14-16-37
```

And I need grep only folders with date names like "2011-08-05_03-01-15"
I tried ls | grep '201' but in output comes 201 folder to

way with ls | grep '2011' is do not acceptable, because it is a hardcode.

Comment: More appropriate for [unix.se.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: not really, this is an appropriate programming question, people do use bash for scripting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `grep`:

```
ls -d */ | grep -E '[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2}_([0-9]{2}-){2}[0-9]{2}'
```

---

With `find`:

```
find * -regextype posix-extended \ 
       -regex '[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2}_([0-9]{2}-){2}[0-9]{2}' \
       -type d
```

Comment: Don't forget the -type d on find.

Comment: @jhclark: yes. atleast, i did for `ls`. +1.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that without grep:

```
ls -d ????-??-??_??-??-??
```

This works fine assuming you don't have other folder names following the same pattern without being dates, like `aaaa-bb-cc_dd-ee-ff`, as those will also be listed by the above command.

You can even be less restrictive and list everything that has a `-` on the 5th position:

```
ls -d ????-*
```

Comment: Be careful with this one though. Expansion of ???'s tend to be done by the shell (e.g. bash) and not the receiving program. The result is that if there are too many directories that match this pattern, older shells give an error about the argument list being too long.

Answer (score 1):

```
ls | egrep '^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with regExp:

ls | grep -E "....-*-*_*-*-*"

Answer (score 0):

You have all the information in man pages.
Have a look at [*find*](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find)